# Can't find Magick-config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ImageMagick / RMagick - Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894225/imagemagick-rmagick-cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magick-config)

I am getting the following error when I try to run my dev console (MAC OS X / Snow Leopard).  Does anyone know the solution?

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in .:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem because I didn't include a library for a specific gem. Check your gems and see if they depend on a library which image gems always do.

```
config.gem gem_name, :lib => 'path_of_your_library'
```

Answer (score 16):

I solved it by Installing `libmagickwand-dev`

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev  
gem install rmagick
```

---

Before, I was getting following error (even after installing `libmagick9-dev`):

```
apt-get install libmagick9-dev
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
Package libmagick9-dev is a virtual package provided by:
libmagickwand-dev 7:6.4.5.4.dfsg1-1ubuntu3.1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package libmagick9-dev has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 14):

It seems that this problem is common in time to install the RMagick gem ... I had the same problem, and I've found the solution in this same site. Follow the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config).

Solution:

sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev

Comment: yes i tried this but get apt-get command not found. so what is apt-get ?

Comment: It seems that this dependency was changed on another: graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat