# ImageMagick / RMagick - Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I used a script to install ImageMagick http://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl

After a while, I got ImageMagick installed.

Then I ran sudo gem install rmagick and got

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in...
```

I'm working in OSX Snow Leopard with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rmagick gem install "Can't find Magick-config"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config)

Answer (score 107):

I was getting the same error and it got resolved after installing the libmagick9-dev library on ubuntu 11.

**Update**  (Thanks to the commenters - Dec. 2012)

`$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` or `$ sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` for ubuntu 12

`$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` or `$ sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev` for ubuntu 11 or below.

`$ yum install ImageMagick-devel` for centos

`$ brew install imagemagick` for Mac OS (using Homebrew)

Comment: This fixed this same issue for me on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev` fixed for me on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat fixed it for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: On Centos I used `yum install ImageMagick-devel`

Comment: Ubuntu 12... `sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` worked for me.

Comment: for Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS [precise], Package libmagick9-dev is not available. but libmagickwand-dev fixed the problem.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` fixed my issue on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I have a clean Ubuntu 12.04 box. `libmagickwand-dev` worked. `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` did not. It complained about a missing Magickwand.h, and I had to purge it. As a side note, don't try to install both.

Comment: Actually for my case I need both

Comment: `cd /usr/ports/graphics/ruby-rmagick && make install clean` for FreeBSD (or the according package).

Comment: Look at this answer if it still doesn't work. You will need to add a source in order for dependencies to install http://stackoverflow.com/a/18474776/1612469

Comment: How do I get the header files NOT using yum?

Answer (score 55):

you need the imagemagick libraries under ubuntu

`$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

it contains all missing libraires

then run **`bundle install`** command

Answer (score 25):

I believe you need the Imagemagick libraries.

If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (which I'd highly recommend), simply do

```
$ brew install imagemagick
```

Then rerun bundle install

Comment: this did it for me. thank you thank you, id been trying various ways for hours

Comment: Did not fixed for me. Installation lacks:
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no; -lMagick... no; -lMagick++... no

Comment: Sadfuzzy I have the same problem, find a solution?

Comment: sadfuzzy and Jackson Gariety, same problem here too. Any solution?

Comment: @sincospi RMagick expects for Homebrew to provide certain symlinks which don't exist. You can run [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4583529) to create the symlinks specific to your ImageMagick installation that are needed for RMagick to work.

Answer (score 8):

Mac OS Mountain Loin (using Homebrew)

1. download and install http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.2
2. `brew install imagemagick`
3. `gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

works well for Ubuntu 12.10

This is assuming you have installed all other dependencies viz.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick ruby ruby-dev gem`
```

Comment: How does this help someone using OSX Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 5.7, I got it to work by first specifying `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/src/ImageMagick-6.7.5-10/magick/

gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who got

```
InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no; -lMagick... no; -lMagick++... no;
```

this worked for me in OS X 10.8: https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer

From here: [RVM + Ruby 1.9.2 + Rmagick + Lion = System Works, RVM Doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007981/rvm-ruby-1-9-2-rmagick-lion-system-works-rvm-doesnt)

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I came around to installing rmagick because it seemed to be a dependency when I tried installing `libgtk2.0-dev`. I was trying to install that package, because the `RGtk2.0` is a requirement for using R package called `rattle`.

Anyway, none of the above solutions worked for me in installing in my Ubuntu 12.04. Even running `sudo apt-get update` first didn't seem to help, nor this related posting: [Installing rmagick on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704919/installing-rmagick-on-ubuntu)

I eventually found what works is to troubleshoot using sudo `aptitude` rather than `apt-get`.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

I recommend the technique of using `aptitude` to work through the package installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Os X, check if `/opt/local/bin` is in your `PATH`. If not:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
sudo gem install rmagick
```

This worked for me!

Comment: +1 This was exactly what I needed. I thought if you had MacPorts installed this was already supposed to be in there though...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue installing Rmagick gem version 2.13.2 on Debian Jessie. After fighting with the packages in the other answers, I upgraded the version of the Rmagick gem from 2.13.2 to the latest (2.16.0 at time of writing). This installed successfully.

```
bundle update rmagick
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all solutions, of all posts of whole Internet, have installed and reinstalled many times all indicated packages in all Linux or Mac distributions/versions (even in Windows) and it still not working, close your terminal and open it again. Some times, even if your reload all shell environment, only after I reopen the terminal the bundle install was successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of searching, my problema was related to some missing libraries, and the one that get the gem installed was this one:

`brew install pkg-config`

after this I did my bundle install again and it worked.