# RVM + Ruby 1.9.2 + Rmagick + Lion = System Works, RVM Doesn't

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-lion, rmagick, homebrew

I've installed Ruby 1.9.2 through RVM on a fresh install of OS X Lion. I have installed ghostscript and imagemagick through homebrew, and when running gem install rmagick using RVM, it fails. When using gem install rmagick on the system install of ruby, it works just fine.

This is the error that is produced:

```
    ─wedtm@WedHQ  ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/cache ‹ruby-1.8.7› 
╰─$ gem install rmagick                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1 ↵
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/wedtm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/wedtm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib
    --with-Magick++lib
    --without-Magick++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/wedtm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/wedtm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

What could be causing this? Any ideas on how to get RVM to see the imagemagick like it's should?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magick-installer script ( https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer ) does a fantastic job of installing ImageMagick on the mac. When I installed without using this script, the install would appear to succeed but the gem would never find the installation.

Using this script, I succeeded with installation where I had failed many times previously. Good luck :)

Comment: Did this fix the problem for you?

Comment: No idea why, but this did the trick. At least until next time I run into some issue with Rails and ImageMagick...

Comment: Wow, AWESOME! This helped me out big time. I had trying installing ImageMagick with Brew, but was never able to install Rmagick. This did the trick. One question: How do I uninstall ImageMagick after installing it using this method?