# Can't install rmagick gem on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick

When I try to install rmagic with:

```
gem install rmagic
```

it gives error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/biske/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/biske/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/biske/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/biske/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

I tried to search for problem and found that I am missing libmagickwand-dev. I tried to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

but it raises error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
```

it gives error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickcore-dev : Depends: librsvg2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-dev
```

it gives error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 librsvg2-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.23.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install libglib2.0-dev with:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

it gives error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.36.0-1ubuntu1) but 2.36.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.36.0-1ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I install libglib2.0-0 with:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0
```

it gives:

```
libglib2.0-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If I install libglib2.0-bin with:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-bin
```

it gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglib2.0-bin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Those 2 libs are installed but issuing again:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

it gives same error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.36.0-1ubuntu1) but 2.36.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.36.0-1ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What could be problem here?

I am using Ubuntu 13.04, rbenv, ruby 2.0.0, if that matters.

Comment: have you installed imagemagick?

Comment: run this command on your terminal 'sudo apt-get install -f'.

Comment: wow, you just explained the exact same problem that I was having! Thanks

Comment: If nothing works for you, follow this link:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution is to add ppa where those libs could be found.

Add PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
```

Then update package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: wow, and you gave the exact solution that I needed! the `add-apt` solved the problem and the rest of the steps. thanks!

Answer (score 16):

try this out

first install imagemagick

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: I was having this issue too having installed libmagickwand-dev only.  Once I installed imagemagick, the gem compiled with no problems.

Comment: I tried libmagickwand-dev repeatedly (with remove and autoremove betweentimes), and it repeatedly failed. Installing imagemagick first was a magic bullet. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing your apt repository and removing any broken packages first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If the system identifies any broken packages, forcefully remove them (replace `package_name` with your own):

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

Then reinstall any missing packages again.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: That's NOT sufficient, at least on Ubuntu 12.04. It failed repeatedly until I installed imagemagick first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good example on this [blog](http://swaeku.github.io/blog/2013/03/23/install-rmagick-on-ubuntu-1210/)

The below command will solve your problem. It helped me to install **rmagick**.

```
sudo apt-get install libdjvulibre-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev libwmf-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libmagick++-dev
```

Comment: After all above solutions failed for me..I just Googled and found above blog. works perfectly..

Comment: Probably you have other Ubuntu version, or meanwhile Ubuntu added libmagickwand-dev to 13.10 repositories.

Comment: Which is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu version 13.04...:)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. sudo apt-get install libcairo2=1.14.6-1 --reinstall
2. sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
3. sudo gem install rmagick