# Can't install RMagick 2.16.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageMagick / RMagick - Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894225/imagemagick-rmagick-cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magick-config)

Comment: Paste the whole error log

Answer (score 8):

Had the exact same problem. The following fixed it for me, using Ubuntu Linux:

```
sudo apt-get update
...
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
...
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
...
bundle install
```

You may have to run `bundle update` if you have other dependency issues, as I did. Good luck!