# rmagick gem install "Can't find Magick-config"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, imagemagick, rvm, rmagick

I get the error shown below when attempting to install the rmagick gem. I am on Snowleopard 10.6 using RVM, Ruby 1.9.2-head and Rails 3.05. Responses to similar questions recommended installing ImageMagick, which I successfully did. Other suggested installing the "libmagick9-dev library", however, I can not figure out how to do this.

I'm a new developer, and any assistance or directions to an existing explanation or resource is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
jjdevenuta(opal)$ gem install rmagick
Fetching: rmagick-2.13.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/jjdevenuta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /Users/jjdevenuta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails3/bin:/Users/jjdevenuta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin:/Users/jjdevenuta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/jjdevenuta/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jjdevenuta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
```

**UPDATE**
If you're a Mac/OS X user I would HIGHLY recommend using Homebrew as your package installer/manager. You can find it [HERE](https://brew.sh/). Since originally asking this question I have removed all my prior installs of things like rmagick and imagemagick, and reinstalled them using Homebrew. Super easy with a huge catalog of packages, and updates/uninstalls are a cinch as well!

Comment: are you using fink, macports, or homebrew?

Comment: I have macports, but used the binary download for snow leopard on the imagemagick site. I can't find anywhere to download/install from for the libmagick9-dev.

Comment: If you update the best answer to @Travis R 's answer would be good

Comment: Brew didn't work for me so I used the magick-installer (https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer) and it worked perfect.

Comment: For Ubuntu ver. >= 12

Solution is in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093006/ubuntu-12-10-ruby-gem-rmagick-missing-dependency-issue/17212648#17212648

Comment: You can check my earlier answer to the same problem and relevant discussions at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4178174/143179

Comment: It is a duplicate of [Can't find Magick-config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756908/cant-find-magick-config)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageMagick / RMagick - Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894225/imagemagick-rmagick-cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magick-config)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

When building native Ruby gems, sometimes you'll get an error containing  "ruby extconf.rb". This is often caused by missing development libraries for the gem you're installing, or even Ruby itself.

Do you have `apt` installed on your machine? If not, I'd recommend installing it, because it's a quick and easy way to get a lot of development libraries.

If you see people suggest installing "libmagick9-dev", that's an apt package that you'd install with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
```

or on centOs:

```
$ yum install ImageMagick-devel
```

On Mac OS, you can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: I successfully installed apt-get via the fink project as you suggested (Thanks). However, apt-can't seem to find the package. "sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package libmagick9-dev" - I'm at a lost now.

Comment: I was getting "Can't install RMagick 2.12.2. Can't find Magick-config in..." on Ubuntu 11.04. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I too was getting "Can't find Magick-config" on (Mint) Linux and installing the libmagick++-dev made the problem go away. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem and couldn't install libmagick9-dev due to some weird depdendency issues (http://askubuntu.com/questions/112548/rmagick-install-problem). I was able to install RMagick in the end with apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev.

Comment: on CentOS I needed `yum install ImageMagick-devel`

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) I used the answer that @TravisR provided, specifying the package `libmagickwand-dev`

Comment: I second James P McGrath for Debian 6.

Comment: Package libmagick9-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` <<< Installing this package worked for me.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04 I also installed `libmagickwand-dev` to get `rmagick-2.13.2` to install.

Comment: Please edit with sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev for your ubuntu instructions

Comment: Fink is kind of outdated; I wouldn't recommend using it anymore. And as others have said, Homebrew is a better Mac package manager than Fink ever was.

Comment: I've removed the reference to fink in the answer.

Comment: On homebrew, you may need to run `brew link --overwrite imagemagick` after install.

Comment: Not only did I need libmagickwand-dev, but also imagemagick
So I had to run:
`sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev`

Comment: If you are working on a project with an older version of rmagick (i.e. 2.13), you may have to `bundle update rmagick` for it to work with the new versions of imagemagick.  That is what worked for me (and if rmagick is locked at a lower version, you may have to update your Gemfile and/or app to upgrade it to a newer version)

There are a few other suggestions at this thread regarding backwards compatibility issues: 
https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/201#issuecomment-106765516

Answer (score 163):

The new correct way is to install libmagickwand-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Then you should be able to install rmagick no problem.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, after installed I just ran `bundle install` rather than trying to do `sudo gem install rmagick`

Comment: I tried this but ultimately the magick-installer below worked for me on mac

Comment: Works on Debian 7.8 as well. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 but says "libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed"

Answer (score 42):

imagemagick@6 works for me!

```
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43035892/474411)

Comment: I'm also in 2017, and after days, something finally works for me.

Comment: this worked for me in April 2018, and then this if experience any other problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666276/5012862

Comment: Worked for me in 2018 as well.

Comment: 2021 this is what worked for me on Big Sur!

Answer (score 40):

**Ubuntu 15.10**

Note that if you try to install this gem in ubuntu 15.10, then error can happened:

`Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in ...`

All you need is preload PATH variable with additional path to ImageMagick lib.

`PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH"`

then run `gem install rmagick`

[source of solution](https://github.com/rmagick-temp/rmagick/issues/133#issuecomment-102964435)

Comment: And on Ubuntu 18.04 :)

Comment: You saved my bacon with this one. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 22):

**UPDATE**
If you're a Mac/OS X user I would HIGHLY recommend using Homebrew as your package installer/manager. You can find it [HERE](https://brew.sh/). Since originally asking this question I have removed all my prior installs of things like rmagick and imagemagick, and reinstalled them using Homebrew. Super easy with a huge catalog of packages, and updates/uninstalls are a cinch as well!

I finally got it working by utilizing a script for ImageMagick installation on github.

magick-installer ( https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer )

It made a fresh install of ImageMagick, and the RMagick 2.12.2 gem then installed perfectly via bundler.

Thanks to Hulihan Applications for confirming that it was most likely a missing library. I tried the suggestion of using apt-get by installing the package downloader from Fink Project. I ran the following command in terminal, but it couldn't find the libmagick9-dev libary.

> $ sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
> $ Password:
> $ Reading Package Lists... Done
> $ Building Dependency Tree... Done
> $ E: Couldn't find package libmagick9-dev

I need to bone up on my UNIX command line skills. The original copy of ImageMagick that I installed from source is still on the machine, but I don't know where exactly or how to remove it. So much to learn...!

Comment: after hours trying every comment on the web about this, the magick-installer worked (link above) on mac!

Answer (score 14):

Things change...maybe this will help someone else:

`sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev` used to work. But with a later version of imagemagick I needed:

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: Just installing `libmagickcore-dev` and `libmagickwand-dev` worked for me on Ubuntu 12.10. In fact, trying to install `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` throws an error for me.

Comment: tried on ubuntu 16.04 but says "libmagickcore-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
"

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
1) apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

2) gem install rmagick
```

Comment: When doing this on my ubuntu 12.10 install I followed another answer and Ubuntu suggested a package that replaced libmagick9-dev. That package was not compatible. The one listed in this answer is.

Answer (score 8):

For those who don't want to do the build-from-source approach of the (otherwise excellent [installer script by John Maddox](https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer), the following worked for me when installing on CentOS 6.2. (Adjust your package manager as necessary).

```
yum install -y {libwmf,lcms,ghostscript,ImageMagick}{,-devel}
gem install rmagick
```

Again, this is mainly of interest if you use your distro's package manager and would really prefer to keep it sane.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 7):

In some OS you need to use new libraries: **libmagick++4 libmagick++-dev**

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++4 libmagick++-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

Important:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++4 libmagick++-dev
```

works on linux mint 13 after making updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 5):

Can't install **RMagick 2.13.2. in ubuntu 17.10**

My decision

```
 - sudo apt-get purge imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
 - sudo apt-get autoremove
 - sudo rm /usr/bin/Magick-config

 - sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

Version is required to correctly specify the path to the configuration

> - cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> - View version ImageMagick, my version ImageMagick - 6.9.7.
> - cd ImageMagick-6.9.7/
> - ls
> - look at the name of the directory *bin-**q**16* or bin-**Q**16

Creating a link to the config

> sudo ln -s
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-**version**/**bin-directory**/Magick-config
>   /usr/bin/Magick-config

Creating for my version ImageMagick

```
 - sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7/bin-q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config
 - bundle
```

Answer (score 3):

in ubuntu 15.10

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

I had to specify version 6

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link --overwrite --force imagemagick@6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error similar like:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore4-extra (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

You might want to start with this package: `sudo apt-get install libgvc5`

For more details: https://askubuntu.com/a/230958/6506

Answer (score 1):

I ran this issue twice on different machine, first time it was resolved by installing the libmagick9-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
```

and second time i have to install the following libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++4 libmagick++-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X `sudo port install ImageMagick` turned out to work fine to fix the `gem install rmagick` problem .   I just didn't know that it worked fine because rvm during installation blew away my .bash_profile contents which included MacPort's addition of `/opt/local/bin` to PATH.   I put back /opt/local/bin into PATH in my .bash_profile and then my `gem install rmagick` then succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I had already installed ImageMagick with macports. I ran

```
    port contents ImageMagick | grep config
```

To find where the config file had been stored and then ran

```
    PATH=(insert your path here):${PATH} bundle
```

to install the gem using bundler. From now on, if you run a command that needs to reference ImageMagick, you can prefix it with that command. For example I had a migration that referenced it, so I ran

```
    PATH=/opt/local/bin/:${PATH} rake db:migrate
```

opt/local/bin/ is the path where my config file was stored.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix the problem on Ubuntu was

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
$ sudo apt-get install ImageMagick
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev libmagickcore-dev
gem install rmagick
```

**CentOS:**

```
yum remove ImageMagick
gem uninstall rmagick
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick-last-libs ImageMagick-c++ ImageMagick-c++-devel
gem install rmagick
```

**MacOS:**

download and install http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.2

after:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew link xz jpeg freetype    
brew install imagemagick
brew link --overwrite imagemagick
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 1):

execute this in terminal

```
  sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

if its not work than

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/local/bin/Magick-config
```

[for reference](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1135-installing-rmagick-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Installing rmagick gem in Ubuntu

sudo aptitude Install Imagemagick and GraphicsMagick(If not aptitude go & install in s/w center)
sudo aptitude Install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick -v 2.13.1

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS 5/6 this is what worked for me

```
yum remove ImageMagick
yum install tcl-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel ghostscript-devel bzip2-devel freetype-devel libtiff-devel
mkdir /root/imagemagick
cd /root/imagemagick
wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xzvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-*
./configure --prefix=/usr/ --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes
make
make install
```

For 64 bit do this

```
cd /usr/lib64
ln -s ../lib/libMagickCore.so.3 libMagickCore.so.3 
ln -s ../lib/libMagickWand.so.3 libMagickWand.so.3
```

Add the missing dependencies

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel
```

Then finally rmagick

```
gem install rmagick
```

If you need to start fresh remove other installs first with

```
cd /root/imagemagick/ImageMagick-*
make uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, you also have to install `imagemagick` and `libmagickcore-dev` like this :

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Everything is written in [the doc](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, I fixed this on debian 8.3 using information here:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/18142073-can-t-install-gem-on-ubuntu-15-04
Specifically:

```
sudo apt-get purge graphicsmagick graphicsmagick-dbg imagemagick-common imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6-headers libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to ckeck the archive Gemfile.lock after the instalation.
Remove this archive and execute bundle again.
It works for me in linux :D