# Ubuntu 12.10 - Ruby gem rmagick missing dependency issue

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick

Like many others I'm having trouble installing rmagick on Ubuntu when running bundle install.

I get this error on the bundle install command:

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/selfsale/.bundler/tmp/2908/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/selfsale/.bundler/tmp/2908/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then did some searching and found some suggestions for adding the missing libs:

sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libmagick9-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

E: Package 'libmagick9-dev' has no installation candidate
```

sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat : Depends: libgraphicsmagick1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                                       Depends: libgraphicsmagick++1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickcore-dev : Depends: libbz2-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpng-dev
                     Depends: librsvg2-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libwmf-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libmagickwand-dev (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It seems that any attempt to install the correct packages comes up with this problem.

I've just seen a post about installing imagemagick from source so I'm going to try that, but if anyone has any better ideas I'd love to hear them.

Thanks

Comment: It won't directly solve your problem, but once you get issues with `bundle install`, it's worth falling back to `gem install` for the specific problem gem. It's slightly quicker, and just sometimes behaves differently enough to give you a better clue to the problem. Once solved, you can go back to `bundle install` for your project again.

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then fire:

```
sudo aptitude install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
```

When asked:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
 Keep the following packages at their current version
1)     graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat [Not Installed]
2)     libexif-dev [Not Installed]
3)     libgraphicsmagick++1-dev [Not Installed]
4)     libgraphicsmagick1-dev [Not Installed]
```

Answer: "n"

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

In second question:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Downgrade the following packages: 
1) libexif12 [0.6.20-2ubuntu0.1 (now) -> 0.6.20-2 (precise)]
```

Answer: "Y" or hit ENTER

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Wait until task end ;)

Answer (score 8):

I just tried on my laptop (Ubuntu 13.04).

```
gem install rmagick
```

failed too. Then I did

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

and rmagick installed without problems.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Philipp, but sadly this also gives me dependency errors. I'll add it to the list.

Comment: @eb_dev: I managed to replicate the original fault in the OP, on an Ubuntu 12.10 system (server build, no GUI), and Ruby 1.8.7-p371, then did `sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev` and rmagick install for me. If you haven't updated for a while, I think it's worth trying again after a `sudo apt-get update`  . . .

Comment: Hrm ok. I cannot reproduce the problem. But have a look at this askubuntu page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

It gives a lot of possible solutions to the unmet dependency problem.

Comment: @PhilippTessenow Thanks Neil, I've got up to the point of purging PPAs, run out of time now so I think I'm going to have to pay someone else to help. Will post back with their solution.

Answer (score 5):

This solution is after all more important than shown before, cuz it removes:

*graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat*

but solves problem with (in 'bundle install'):

```
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
```

as show in my second post type in prompt:

```
sudo aptitude install libmagickwand-dev
```

At:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

  Keep the following packages at their current version
1)      libatk1.0-dev [Not Installed]
2)      libcairo2-dev [Not Installed]
3)      libexpat1-dev [Not Installed]
4)      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev [Not Installed]
5)      libglib2.0-dev [Not Installed]
6)      libgraphviz-dev [Not Installed]
7)      libgtk2.0-dev [Not Installed]
8)      libmagickcore-dev [Not Installed]
9)      libmagickwand-dev [Not Installed]
10)     libpango1.0-dev [Not Installed]
11)     librsvg2-dev [Not Installed]
```

Answer:

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

In secound:

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
  Remove the following packages: 
1 ) graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
Install the following packages:
2)libcairo-script-interpreter2 [1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2 (precise)]
[..]
```

Answer: "Y"

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

After task is done, U can easily run `'bundle install'` in your project directory.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing imagemagick and libmagickwand-dev together:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

This allows apt to resolve the dependencies properly. (tested on Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

rmagick installed success