# Ubuntu - cannot install RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rmagick

How to install the RMagick gem to Ubuntu? I found a few threads here on SO, some of there directly pointed out to the installation on Ubuntu systems, but none of them is working for me.

Here is the output that I got if I run **sudo gem install rmagick**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /opt/bitnami/common/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.7.5 Q16 is installed in /opt/bitnami/common
         /usr/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.6.9 Q16 is installed in /usr
Using 6.7.5 Q16 from /opt/bitnami/common.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

It's on Amazon EC2 servers.
If I try to run just **gem install rmagick**, I get

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.
```

Could you help me, please, how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much

**EDIT:** What I've tried:

1. sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     libgraphicsmagick3 libmagick++4 libgraphicsmagick++3 libgraphicsmagick1-dev
     libgraphics-magick-perl libperl5.14 libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
   ```
2. sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick

   Reading package lists... Done
       Building dependency tree
       Reading state information... Done
       imagemagick is already the newest version.
       libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.
       The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
         libgraphicsmagick3 libmagick++4 libgraphicsmagick++3 libgraphicsmagick1-dev
         libgraphics-magick-perl libperl5.14 libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
       Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
3. apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

   E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
4. sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
     libgraphicsmagick3 libmagick++4 libgraphicsmagick++3 libgraphicsmagick1-dev
     libgraphics-magick-perl libperl5.14 libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.

But still the same error message above.

Comment: You should really post what you've tried that didn't work, or people are just going to give you all the same answers again.

Comment: there is already a Q/A on superuser about this http://superuser.com/questions/163818/how-to-install-rmagick-on-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: Please, see the update OP.

Comment: I used bitnami instance some days ago, and I had not to install rmagick, do you  need a newer version? you can try setting version in Gemfile same as instance `gem 'rmagick', 'the_version_in_the_instance'`. I suppose you can get the version in the instance with `rmagick -v`

Comment: @juanpastas well, if I run in the console `rmagick -v`, I get `Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.2.44`

Comment: What do you think of recreating instance again? :p

Comment: Try these:

sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev

and then:

bundle

Answer (score 35):

Looking at the error output, you're missing one of the dependencies for rmagick. Try

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

and then try

```
gem install rmagick
```

The second problem is probably due to permission issues. More info on what steps you took would be helpful for us to provide you with better answers.

Comment: Hello, I've tried this command (the bullet #3). I am not sure about the permissions, is there something like a **permission reset**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17212105/3185510

Comment: or just add `sudo` in front of it :)

Comment: You are the MAN!