# Carrierwave/RMagick NoMethodError after upgrade to ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick, ruby-2.0

I upgraded my app from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.0, keeping most of my gems without upgrade.
Everything worked fine, but when I tried to upload an image, I got this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass:
  app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:91:in `block in optimize'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:263:in `manipulate!'
  app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:90:in `optimize'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:85:in `block in process!'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
  /home/stefpe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@Lefkada/bundler/gems/carrierwave-5ee108128b40/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
```

The image_uploader.rb is based on     /carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb example      `manipulate` function:

```
  def optimize
    manipulate! do |img, index, options|
      options[:write] = {
    :quality => 50,
    :depth => 8,
    :interlace => "Magick::PlaneInterlace"
      }
      img.strip!
    end
  end
```

Configuration:
Server: heroku, local dev: linux

ruby 1.9.3 -> 2.0

rails 3.2.13

carrierwave 0.6.2

rmagick 2.13.1

fog 1.3.1

Any idea for why there is no compatibility with ruby-2.0.0?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you be so nice and include excerpt with line 91 as error msg says?

Answer (score 0):

I did:
    sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

and then
    gem install rmagick

it worked.
see:
[rmagick gem install "Can't find Magick-config"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config)

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating some gems—carrierwave may not have been fully compatible with ruby 2 in April of 2012.

Further incentive: Carrierwave [didn't](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L263) even pass the options into the block passed to `manipulate!` until [0.7](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.7.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L330).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to return the image at the end of manipulate! 
In your case :

```
def optimize
  manipulate! do |img, index, options|
    options[:write] = {
      :quality => 50,
      :depth => 8,
      :interlace => "Magick::PlaneInterlace"
    }
    img.strip!
    img
  end
end
```