# Rails: Error installing rmagick - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run one project on my local machine. I installed Ruby and Rails on my Mac OS system. It is working properly. I can create a new project and can run it properly without any error, but when I try to run the existing project it says that we have to `bundle install`. When I run that command I get the following error:

```
"An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling."
```

When I run `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

I have searched and did not find an answer anywhere.

Comment: You'll need to install rmagick's dev libraries as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config) answer.

Answer (score 89):

For Ubuntu, I used the ff. based on this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/yrfyjw):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

Comment: Error still exists after installing this lib.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed

Answer (score 51):

On a mac (the below code works on OSX Mavericks):

```
brew install imagemagick
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: edited for clarity. This worked great for me and @Anand Soni below has the explanation of why you get the error in the first place.

Comment: Worked for me. OSX El Capitan 10.11.5.

Answer (score 45):

On Mac you can try this:

```
$ brew unlink imagemagick
$ brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
$ gem install rmagick
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. My installation of `rmagick` is not compatible with `imagemagick@7.x`, which is what `brew` will install by default if you simply issue `brew install imagemagick`

Comment: I don't know why this answer doesn't have enough upvotes. This is so correct. +1

Comment: That's the only way you can fix your `catpix` installation!

Answer (score 13):

I have solved this problem by installing imagemagic:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

and then install libmagick package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

Answer (score 9):

For Linux Fedora, I got same error and fixed with below two commands:

```
yum install ImageMagick

gem install rmagick
```

For Centos install `ImageMagick-devel` package. using below commands:

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel

gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 7):

First, make sure you've installed `Imagemagick` :

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Now, it can build the gem native extension.

Then, install the `Rmagick` gem :

```
$ sudo gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Simply installing `imagemagick` wasn't enough on a new install of Ubuntu 17.04. I needed to also install `libmagick++-dev` too as @Sirajus Salayhin's comment

Answer (score 6):

here's what i did on 16.04,

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
```

and then install gem like that

```
PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH" gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
```

Comment: Perfect! After all the solutions, this worked for me on my Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

May be you are installing ImageMagick version 7.x.x which will generate different folder names in your `usr/lib/local/include/ImageMagick7.x.x` folder. 
E.g.

In ImageMagick6.x.x version we have `magick`, `wand` named folders, where in ImageMagick7.x.x version have named this `MagickCore` , `MagickWand` . So this updation is causing the problem in some gem installation like here. Which is using 
`magick/some_header.h` or `wand/some_header.h` (Means they are not updated with the new 7.x.x ImageMagick version).That's why we are getting this error :

```

```
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no
 .... 
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
```

```

and in log file something like this :

```
error: 'MagickCore/method-attribute.h' file not found
#include "MagickCore/method-attribute.h"
         ^
```

**Solution**

Install the ImageMagick6.x.x version in your system from the official site : https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ and install it using this commands(after extract zip/tar) :

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Then do

`gem install rmagick`

It will work.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when setting up a **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

**Here's how I solved it**

**RMagick** is an interface between the **Ruby** programming language and the **ImageMagick** image processing library. So we first need to install development libraries for **ImageMagick**:

**Step 1**:

On **Ubuntu**, you can run:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

On **Centos**, you can run:

```sh
sudo yum install gcc ImageMagick-devel make which
```

On **Arch Linux**, you can run:

```sh
pacman -Syy pkg-config imagemagick
```

On **Alpine Linux**, you can run:

```
apk add pkgconfig imagemagick imagemagick-dev imagemagick-libs
```

or you can run if you would like to use ImageMagick 6:

```
apk add pkgconfig imagemagick6 imagemagick6-dev imagemagick6-libs
```

On **macOS**, you can run:

```sh
brew install pkg-config imagemagick
```

or you can run if you would like to use ImageMagick 6:

```sh
brew install pkg-config imagemagick@6
```

On **Windows**:

1. Install the latest Ruby+Devkit package which you can get from [RubyInstaller for Windows](https://rubyinstaller.org).
2. You might need to configure `PATH` environment variable to where the compiler is located.
   (Ex: `set PATH=C:\Ruby27-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Ruby27-x64\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%`)
3. Download `ImageMagick-7.XXXX-Q16-x64-dll.exe` (not, `ImageMagick-7.XXXX-Q16-x64-static.exe`) binary from [Windows Binary Release](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), or you can download ImageMagick 6 from [Windows Binary Release](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).
4. Install ImageMagick. You need to turn on checkboxes `Add application directory to your system path` and `Install development headers and librarries for C and C++` in an installer for RMagick.

**Step 2**:

Install the **RMagick** ruby gem:

```
gem install rmagick
```

**Step 3**:

Now you can add the **RMagick** ruby gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rmagick', '~> 4.1'
```

**Note**: As of this writing the latest version is `4.1`

**Step 4**:

Finally, you can run `bundle install` to install the gem to your application.

**Resources**:  [rmagick/rmagick GitHub page](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

As per the error log it looks like "Magick-config" is missing.
You need to install ImageMagik or GraphicsMagick. These are the commands you should follow which is taken from [RMagik Documentation](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-linux.html):

```
1) Go to http://www.imagemagick.org or http://www.graphicsmagick.org and download the latest version of the software to a temporary directory. the extract them :

- tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
- cd ImageMagick-x.x.x

- ./configure --disable-static --with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8

- make
- sudo make install

- sudo gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

`ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config`

Answer (score 2):

first run this:
`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

then: `sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev`

now install rmagick: `gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 2):

Just run these command

```
• $ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
• $ sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
• $ sudo gem install rmagick
• $ bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install ImageMagick-devel package and everything should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu Server, I installed it by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick

sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev

sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4'
```

Comment: May also need sudo apt-get install ruby-all-dev if you get error mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

Answer (score 1):

All here wrong for me :(

this helped:

`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

according to [rmagick github page](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick)

then bundle install went with no errors

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openSUSE, then first check if the `ImageMagick` installed or not. If it is installed, then do install it development header file.

```
[arup@sztukajedzenia]$ sudo zypper se imagemagic
root\'s password:

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name              | Summary                                               | Type
--+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------
i | ImageMagick       | Viewer and Converter for Images                       | package
  | ImageMagick       | Viewer and Converter for Images                       | srcpackage
  | ImageMagick-devel | Include Files and Libraries Mandatory for Development | package
  | ImageMagick-doc   | Document Files for ImageMagick Library                | package
  | ImageMagick-extra | Viewer and Converter for Images - extra codecs        | package
[arup@sztukajedzenia]$ sudo zypper in ImageMagick-devel
root\'s password:
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 2 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  ImageMagick-devel libbz2-devel
  ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run both the command for ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then try to install

```
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac users, install imagemagick 6 since the newest version 7 isn't compatible.

```
brew install imagemagick@6
gem install rmagick
```

The above should work after you uninstall what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 27 I resolved this problem:

```
sudo dnf install ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick
gem install rmagick
```