# An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0) [I tried all option provided in Duplicate but same issue persisit]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick, ubuntu-16.04

**I 'm on Ubuntu 16.04** ,
in gemfile I have `gem "rmagick"` and when I `bundle` it says

```
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

as suggested above when I try `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` it says

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/faisal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
/home/faisal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160926-26223-16sn0dg.rb extconf.rb
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
checking for pkg-config... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/faisal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/faisal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/faisal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/faisal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

I have tried dozen of different ways provided in different questions but none of the work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing rmagick: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274293/error-installing-rmagick-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: @Deepak
I tried all solution provided in DUPLICATE QUESTION but same issue persist

Answer (score 30):

In MacOS, you can do this:

```
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

Comment: actually it fixed my issue

Comment: Sadly, 2 years later and this is still necessary.

Comment: thank you. works on my 2017 macbook pro bigsur

Answer (score 12):

Try this, You need to run the following commands for ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then try to install

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: while installing libmagick++-dev it says "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
"

Comment: use sudo apt-get clean to clear cache and sudo apt-get autoremove, and use sudo apt-get update ,then try to install with following steps as we mention above

Comment: I did "clean, autoromove and update" and followed these steps but same issue

Answer (score 2):

the only thing that worked for me was

```
brew unlink pkgconfig
bundle install
brew link pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu you should first install this

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Then install `gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 1):

On mac/osx, make sure you `brew install imagemagick@6` (NOT 7)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac High Sierra - 10.13.4 - https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

```
sudo port install ImageMagick   
sudo gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora (when I installed Redmine) that worked for me:

```
sudo dnf install ImageMagick-devel
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dependencies from Imagemagick which are required for **rmagick** gem to work

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Once done, bundle should execute successfully and install the gems.

Comment: Try installing sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev , then restart your terminal

Comment: on trying this it says "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

and install Imagemagick

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then, install the rmagick gem :

```
$ sudo gem install rmagick
```

Comment: at first commnad it says "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
"

Comment: Add PPA:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
Then update package list:

sudo apt-get update
then use sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

Comment: @vipin gems should not be installed with sudo privileges, try to install gems at a project level to avoid screwing up your system in long run.

Comment: Try to refer this link. though not sure if it's the same issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Answer (score 0):

Type in the following commands on the console -

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

Let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: at the very first command it says "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libmagick9-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

E: Package 'libmagick9-dev' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX 10.12.3, I have also tried many methods to install rmagick and finally I solved my problem.

brew doctor says
............

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  imagemagick

Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:
  imagemagick@6

I did

```
>brew unlink imagemagick@6
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.7-9... 60 symlinks removed
>brew link imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.7-3... 75 symlinks created
```

then

```
 >gem install rmagick
```

works for me

My advice: Try to install correct version of imagemagick and listen brew doctors advice.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game but the following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

Probably overkill a bit but first you'll want to enable all `deb-src` lines in your sources.list:

`sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`

Then do an apt update:

`sudo apt update`

Now you should be able to install all the required packages:

`sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libpng-dev libwmf-dev libpango1.0-dev librsvg2-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev imagemagick`

(personally I installed `libmagickcore-dev`, `libmagickwand-dev`, `imagemagick` one at a time during my debugging but you should be able to install them all at once)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**For Centos 6 for the and above**

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel

bundle install
```