# Failed to build gem native extension. in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I download redmine in github 
And open the application
After give bundle install

> An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rmagick-2.16.0
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:   rmagick

Comment: Do what it tells you. Start with `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` and then check the logs if it doesn't work. See what the logs tell you.

Comment: _“I download redmine in github And open the application After give bundle install”_ —thanks for sharing; it would be a better fit somewhere on your personal blog, tho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing rmagick: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274293/error-installing-rmagick-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you install Imagemagick first. If you are using ubuntu, then you can use apt-get to install Imagemagick. Also maybe you need to install libmagickwand-dev.