# Unable to install fileutils Rubygem on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

When trying to install fileutils gem I get following output:

```
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/aditya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/aditya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/rmagick-2.13.4/gem_make.out
```

It looks like there is some issue with rmagick, imagemagick is installed properly and on trying to install rmagick gem I get error that a package is missing: libmagickwand-dev

When I try to install this package I get following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This may help [rmagick gem install “Can't find Magick-config”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa/230958#230958

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h

Comment: FileUtils is built into Ruby's std lib, so you don't need to install it. Just use `require 'fileutils'`.

Answer (score 19):

Running `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Install these two packages

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

In your Gemfile add these lines

```
# To perform file operations
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'fileutils', '~> 0.7'
```

Then you can install the gems by running

```
bundle install
```

And as an output of the command you should see something similar to this...

```
...
Installing rmagick 2.13.4
Installing fileutils 0.7
....
Your bundle is complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see that gem has been removed, check [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/fileutils), there's no source available, so if you can you can choose another gem like [metadata](https://github.com/kig/metadata)