# checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... no Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. You must have ImageMagick 6.4.9 or later

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I have trouble installing rmagick. I am developing my project using ruby on rails framework. I included rmagick gem in my gemfile. I am getting the following error message:

```
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. You must have ImageMagick 6.4.9 or later.
```

I have installed imagemagick using brew:

```
 imagemagick-6.8.9-8 already installed
```

The imagemagick folder is resided in /usr/local/Cellar directory

In my terminal:

Zoulfias-iMac:Myapp zoulfiahall$ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p481

```
Using /Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481
Zoulfias-iMac:Myapp zoulfiahall$ sudo gem install rmagick

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. You must have ImageMagick 6.4.9 or later.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/rubies/
ruby-2.0.0-  p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/rubies/
ruby-2.0.0-  p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/
2.0.0-static/rmagick-2.13.4/gem_make.out
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 42):

This worked for me on ubuntu.

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Now try again.

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It works but I also need to install the ruby-rmagick with the command 

`#apt install ruby-rmagick`

Comment: if possible pls try to relate why we need to install these libraries for proper working of ImageMagick. Similarly in other cases as well.

Comment: @RememberWhyYouStarted I have no idea why its needed. It seems like the library has a dependency on the development libraries rather than just the production binaries. I have no idea why, only that it works.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same issue on macOS when attempting to run `gem install rmagick -v 2.13.4`

The trick to this is the rmagick installer (**gems/rmagick-2.13.4/ext/RMagick/extconf.rb**) checks the output of `convert` to determine the IM version. If that is not returning the correct version (or otherwise completely broken, as was my case), rmagick will not install.

I installed ImageMagick 6 via Homebrew and that fixed my issue. This snippet installs IM, adds it to your path, and runs the installer explicitly pointing to IM6.

```
$ brew install imagemagick@6
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick -v 2.13.4
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today.
What is causing the problem is the fact that `rmagick` is out of date.
And the gem is not being updated regularly.
I wanted to present my solution for people who don't mind using older version of imagemagick. ( I believe it is up to 6.5.9-10)

1. Uninstall imagemagick with all the components:

   `brew uninstall --force imagemagick`
2. Install the older version of imagemagick by adding -ruby186 to the end of the command

   `brew install imagemagick-ruby186`
3. Install rmagick :)

   `gem install rmagick`
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

If do you installed imagemagick with brew install imagemagick@6

Before bundle install, run:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had same issue. Try uninstall imagemagick and then install again:

```
brew uninstall --force imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```

Then install rmagick. This worked for me.

Comment: This is the most minimalistic and straight-forward solution here and it worked well for me. I recommend others to try this one before trying the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report for a similar issue at https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/126

I'm running crunchbang linux using debian sid.

It looks like you are on OSX. Consider filing your own bug report, if you havn't already.

Answer (score 0):

download and install http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.2

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew link xz jpeg freetype    
brew install imagemagick
brew link --overwrite imagemagick
gem install rmagick
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055126/3563993

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me in MacOS 10.14 Mojave

```
brew install pkg-config
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.11-0/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick -v 2.16.0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
brew uninstall pkg-config
brew install pkg-config
brew unlink pkg-config
brew link pig-config

sudo gem install rmagick
```

This worked for me.