# Can't install RMagick 0.0.0. Can't find Magick-config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm running a debian server and upgraded all packages after quite a while (`apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get distro-upgrade`). Then rmagick didn't work anymore becuase imagemagick was updated.

So I ran:

```
gem uninstall rmagick
bundle install
```

Then I got this:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 0.0.0. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /srv/www/www.example.com/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /srv/www/www.example.com/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This is `cat mkmf.log`:

```
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_executable: checking for gcc... -------------------- yes

--------------------

find_executable: checking for Magick-config... -------------------- no

--------------------

Can't install RMagick 0.0.0. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For whoever runs into this problem in the future: It took me long but it's fixed. This is what I did:

- `sudo apt-get purge imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`
- `sudo rm -R /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/magick`
- `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config`
- `sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`

Comment: I had the same issue, and this fixed it. However, I did not have to purge then re-install. Instead I only did step 3: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config`

Comment: Same for me just needed to do the symbolic link (using for Docker Debian container)

Comment: I only had to install two missing packages `libmagickcore-dev` and `libmagickwand-dev`

Answer (score 17):

```
apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
```

worked well for me.

Answer (score 12):

I'm on mac os, but I had to specify version 6

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link --overwrite --force imagemagick@6
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to install libmagickwand-dev from the ubuntu archive:

This package included the static libraries needed to compile programs using MagickWand.It contains the MagickWand.h file

This is a transition package that depends on default quantum libmagickwand development files.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

After install this dependency you need to install rmagick:

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added description

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's already installed, it says: `apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
...
libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.`

Comment: It's worked for me. For more solution you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config

Comment: No. I have got the same issue and I have resolved with the same answer twice. First in my local and then server. Can you reinstall imagemagick and see if it will work or not?

Comment: I pruned everything related to imagemagick and reinstalled it, same result.

Answer (score 1):

In centos 7 I had to do the following to make it work:

```
 yum install ImageMagick-devel.x86_64
```

It failed all the time when this package was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but ImageMagic was installed. Symlinking worked but url is slightly different then answers above. Please pay attention to caps. For Ubuntu 18.04 there are 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Add symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7/bin-q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config
```

**Option 2:**

Export path in ~/.profile

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7/bin-q16/:$PATH"
```