# Rmagick Gem 2.13.2 Installation issue in Ruby 2.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rmagick

I have installed Ruby and in my project file i have rmagick gem.

```
gem "rmagick",       "2.13.2", require: "RMagick"
```

Ruby Version 
    gem "rmagick",       "2.13.2", require: "RMagick"
 I am getting an error while installing rmagick.

```
g native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160916-13775-z6z2nl.rb extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.        
You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-        2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1060:in `block in have_header'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
from /home/suganya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1059:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out.
```

i have been working on this for past two days and I tried a lot of work arounds.

sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick

But if I run just
    gem install rmagick

It runs perfect installs rmagick-2.16.0

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324439/cant-install-rmagick-0-0-0-cant-find-magick-config This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following commands for ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then try to install

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Tried this also. It didn't help.

Comment: try to install ImageMagic with this : - sudo apt-get install imagemagick       and then install rmagic with this : -    sudo gem install rmagick

Comment: But using sudo when installing a gem has the risk of breaking the application right?